# Rules email notifications and Users

Tags: users, rules, emails

I have a User field type of 'List (integer)' storing a list of nodes the User has subscribed to i.e. Forum items.
I need to setup a notifications like rule to email all users that have subscribed to a particular Forum item advising them of when a new comment has been posted.

1. Event = After saving a new comment (any user posting to a Forum
   item)
2. Condition = Content is of type (Forum item)
3. Action = ??? basically email all subscribed Users of this Forum item
   advising that a new comment has been posted

Logic something like:

Check each user -> field_list_of_followed_nodes[] where nid == 1 return TRUE

Don't know if this can be done in rules?

Comment: What data is your custom field storing? It would be easier if this were based on the user's Role instead, as there'a an already predefined action to send email to all users containing a particular role.

Comment: Hi Alex, each user needs the ability to subscribe to individual nodes, the field data type is List (integer)containing node ids.

Comment: This has been resolved using Rules and Flags, ill post the full solution when I have time to run through it.

Comment: ah good to hear you found a solution. would be interested to see how you eventually tackled the problem.